# Passing Geolocation from Swift 2 ViewController to Javascript Method

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

The code below is able to get the geolocation and prints it out. I got this based on some tutorials online and looking at Swift Documents. I want to pass geolocations in the form of Strings from Swift 2 to Javascript. I am able to get the GeoLocations, I do not know how to pass these Strings to my Javascript Code in the Webview.

Below is the Code I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Webview: UIWebView!

let locMgr = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadAddressURL()
    locMgr.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locMgr.startUpdatingLocation()
    locMgr.delegate = self //necessary



}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager , didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    let myCurrentLoc = locations[locations.count-1]
    var myCurrentLocLat:String = "\(myCurrentLoc.coordinate.latitude)"
    var myCurrentLocLon:String = "\(myCurrentLoc.coordinate.longitude)"

    print(myCurrentLocLat)
    print(myCurrentLocLon)

    //pass to javascript here by calling setIOSNativeAppLocation

}
```

I have javascript on my website with this method:

```
function setIOSNativeAppLocation(lat , lon){

  nativeAppLat = lat;
  nativeAppLon = lon;
  alert(nativeAppLat);
  alert(nativeAppLon);

}
```

I have looked at another question labelled [Pass variable from Swift to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665754/pass-variable-from-swift-to-javascript-function) with the following solution:

```
func sendSomething(stringToSend : String) {
    appController?.evaluateInJavaScriptContext({ (context) -> Void in

       //Get a reference to the "myJSFunction" method that you've implemented in JavaScript
       let myJSFunction = evaluation.objectForKeyedSubscript("myJSFunction")

       //Call your JavaScript method with an array of arguments
       myJSFunction.callWithArguments([stringToSend])

       }, completion: { (evaluated) -> Void in
          print("we have completed: \(evaluated)")
    })
}
```

However I have no appDelegate, and I want to directly from this view make these changes. So I get a "use of unresolved identifier appDelegate".

Comment: Just a vague idea... Can you enable local storage in webview then set it and read it later from javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement UIWebview delegate.Javascript function should call after webviewDidFinishLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     let url = NSURL (string: URLSTRING);
     let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
webView.delegate = self
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
  }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
            let javaScriptStr = "setIOSNativeAppLocation(\(myCurrentLoc.coordinate.latitude), \(myCurrentLoc.coordinate.longitude))"

            webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javaScriptStr)
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer you link to is for Apple TV, which is very different to iOS & `UIWebView`.

Before you try to run any javascript you need to be sure that the web view has finished loading (see `webViewDidFinishLoad`).

When the web view is ready and you have your details you can create a `String` which contains the javascript you want to execute and then pass that to the web view:

```
let javaScript = "setIOSNativeAppLocation(\(myCurrentLoc.coordinate.latitude), \(myCurrentLoc.coordinate.longitude))"

webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(javaScript)
```